# Retrieve Mail-Attachments in LogicApp for Azure Function call

Tags: email, azure-functions, email-attachments, azure-logic-apps

I have a use case in which I have a Logic App which triggers as soon a Mail is sent to a particular email address.

This email contains multiple attachments. The Logic App then needs to call an Azure Function and pass the Body of the mail and the attachements to the Azure Function.

Actually I am struggling with getting the email attachements in a way (Array?) which allows me to pass them to the Azure Function for further processing.

Does anybody have some advice for me? I'm not very familiar with Logic Apps, so any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Frank. Sorry I was not in the office yesterday. I'll check and give you feedback :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use `HTTP` requests to send attachment, The metadata used in the example can be obtained directly in `Add dynamic content`.

[image]

[image]

You can refer to [Post Multipart/Form-data using Azure Logic Apps](https://medium.com/@devanshijoshi/post-multipart-form-data-using-azure-logic-apps-8902ab1d7c4e).

==================update===========================

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just a question. This seems to call the azure function for each attachment. But what if I need to collect first all attachements and put them in an array and to pass this array to the azure function?

Comment: Maybe you can define a string variable first, and then use `Append to string variable` within `For each` to append all your request bodies. Please pay attention to the format of the request body.